# Zwei Sätze mit Komma trennen, wobei einer der Teilsätze eine Frage ist

Tags: punctuation, comma, interrogative

1. Betrachte diese zwei Sätze:

> Die Antwort auf deine Frage ist "ja". Aber wieso fragst du nochmal (ich habe dir doch schließlich schon geantwortet)?

Wenn man das ausspricht, würde ich die beiden Sätze ziemlich schnell nacheinander sagen. Deswegen finde ich, dass der Punkt hier zu stark trennt. Ich würde lieber gerne ein Komma (oder meinetwegen ein Semikolon) setzen:

> Die Antwort auf deine Frage ist "ja", aber wieso fragst du nochmal?

Aber entspricht dies der korrekten Zeichensetzung? Schließlich ist nur der zweite Teilsatz ein Fragesatz, und mit diesem Fragezeichen am Ende sagt man vielleicht, dass der ganze Satz eine Frage ist (aber der erste Teilsatz "Die Antwort auf deine Frage ist "ja"" ist keine Frage, sondern ein Aussagesatz).

2. Auch interessant ist die Frage, wenn der erste Teilsatz eine Frage ist:

> Wieso fragst du schon wieder, ich habe dir doch schon geantwortet.

Ist die Zeichensetzung in diesem Satz so korrekt, oder müsste man nach "wieder" einen Punkt setzen:

> Wieso fragst du schon wieder? Ich habe dir doch schon geantwortet.

Aber ich würde diese beiden Sätze in einem "Lauf" aussprechen, weswegen ich hier das Gefühl habe, dass hier die Trennung der Sätze zu stark ist.

EDIT: 3. Wo ich mir jetzt so nochmal meine Frage hier durchlese, noch eine Frage, die sich auf mein bis jetzt Geschriebenes bezieht: Ist das Folgende bezüglich der Zeichensetzung korrekt?

> Ist die Zeichensetzung in diesem Satz so korrekt, oder müsste man nach "wieder" einen Punkt setzen:
>
> > Wieso fragst du schon wieder? Ich habe dir doch schon geantwortet.

Schließlich ist das auch eine Frage; aber es steht ja nirgends ein Fragezeichen. Müsste man streng genommen ein Fragezeichen nach dem Zitat von "Wieso fragst du schon wieder? Ich habe dir doch schon geantwortet." setzen? Es steht ja nur ein Doppelpunkt da. Und wenn auf der neuen Zeile nur ein Fragezeichen steht, sieht das auch komisch aus.

Comment: Äh... der letzte Abschnitt... Wo ist da ein Doppelpunkt. Da ist doch schon ein Fragezeichen. Ich raff's nicht.

Comment: Im ersten Fall könnte ein Bindestrich helfen. Die Antwort auf deine Frage ist ja -- aber wieso fragst du nochmal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lustigerweise schweigen sich dazu die [amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_regeln-woerterverzeichnis_inkl_Nachtraegen.pdf) aus. Zwar heißt es in § 70 und § 70 E1:

> § 70: Mit dem Fragezeichen kennzeichnet man den Ganzsatz als Frage.
>
> E1: Wenn aber als mehrteiliger Ganzsatz oder als Teile einer Aufzählung verstanden, entsprechend § 71 mit Komma.

Aber die gegebenen Beispiele in § 70 E1 sich ausschließlich Aneinanderreihungen von *Fragen.* Wie schon des Öfteren hier zu beobachten sind die Rechtschreibregeln dort vage, wo die zweifelhaften Fälle warten.

Dennoch denke ich, dass in beiden Fällen, die du vorschlägst, am Ende des mehrteiligen Ganzsatzes, dessen einer Teil eine Frage ist, ein Fragezeichen stehen sollte. Warum? Relativ unstrittig erscheint es mir bei deiner ersten Version; die Frage ist das zweite Satzglied; wäre sie nicht mit einem Fragezeichen versehen, müsste man sie als rhetorische Frage verstehen. Das ist aber nicht gewollt, also Fragezeichen.

Das gleiche Argument kann auch in deinem zweiten Fall vorgebracht werden. Wir haben es dort mit einem Teilsatz zu tun, der eine Frage ist. Wenn diese Frage aber nicht als Frage markiert ist, woran sollen wir erkennen, ob sie rhetorisch, als versteckte Aufforderung oder sonstwie gemeint ist? Dementsprechend würde ich in beiden Fällen ein Fragezeichen setzen.

Nebenbei: Die entsprechenden Paragraphen zu Ausrufezeichen (für die dieselbe Frage gestellt werden kann) schweigen sich gleichermaßen aus und die Beispiele sind auch nicht aussagekräftiger.

---

Zuletzt die dritte Frage, wie man quasi Fragen markieren sollte, die erst anschließend in einem Blockzitat folgen. Ich habe das bereits mit einer Linie abgesetzt, einfach um zu zeigen, dass wir hier das Gebiet der Rechtschreibung verlassen und dasjenige der Typographie betreten.

Denn bei Blockzitaten, wie sie hier durch vorangestelltes `>` abgesetzt werden, handelt es sich nicht mehr um Bestandteile eines Satzes. Der *vorige* Satz muss vollständig sein; man kann diesen wie einen Hinweis auf eine Abbildung oder eine Tabelle lesen. Es sollte also in der Regel ein Fragezeichen direkt am Ende dieses Satzes gesetzt werden, da er eine Frage darstellt. Folgt das Blockzitat allerdings direkt im Anschluss kann man *stattdessen* auch einen Doppelpunkt setzen, der auf das Nachfolgende hinweist. In diesem Fall wird auf die Kennzeichnung als Frage verzichtet, da die Kennzeichnung »folgendes konkretisiert« wichtiger ist.

Befindet sich der Satz in Anführungszeichen eingeschlossen mitten im Fließtext, spricht nichts dagegen, die üblichen Regeln für Zeichensetzungen mit Zitaten anzuwenden: »Demnach wäre dieser Satz mit einem inneren Punkt zu beenden.« Und was wäre in diesem Fall logischer als: »Hinter diesem Satz muss ein Fragezeichen stehen«? Es kann dabei nicht zu Unklarheiten kommen. Denn wie viele Fragezeichen stehen nach diesem Zitat: »Soll ich dir die Antwort gleich sagen?«? Richtig, es sind zwei (Stichwort: Logische Zeichensetzung). Die entsprechenden Paragraphen der [Rechtschreibregeln](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_regeln-woerterverzeichnis_inkl_Nachtraegen.pdf) sind § 89 ff.

Comment: Setzt man bei rhetorischen Fragen kein Fragezeichen? Ich dachte bis jetzt schon.

Comment: Wo würdest du bei Frage 3. das Fragezeichen setzen? Nach dem Zitat auf einer neuen Zeile?

Comment: @user25172 Gut, dass du mich dranerinnerst; die dritte Frage habe ich irgendwie vollkommen überlesen.

Comment: Aaah, hab den Edit gesehen. Danke. Vielleicht könntest du noch diese Frage beantworten: Setzt man bei rhetorischen Fragen kein Fragezeichen? Ich dachte bis jetzt schon. (Ich wollte jetzt fast schon nochmal ein Fragezeichen setzen :P)

Comment: @user25172 Es ist durchaus möglich, dass ich wieder einen falschen Begriff gewählt habe ;). Worauf ich auf jeden Fall hinauswollte, sind Sätze, die zwar wie Fragen aufgebaut sind, aber keine Fragen sind. À la »Hast du das jetzt endlich kapiert!« Eine Frage ist also nicht etwas syntaktisch erkennbares, sondern sollte auch in irgendeiner Form eine Antwort erwarten. Verstehst du, was ich meine?

Comment: Ja, vielen Dank. Es klappt leider nicht, deine Antwort zu upvoten – bestimmt weil ich als Gast hier bin. Naja, akzeptieren werde ich deine Antwort aber auf jeden Fall.

Comment: @Jan Laut Duden muss das Fragezeichen auch nach rhetorischen Fragen stehen, auf die keine Antwort erwartet wird: „Wirst du denn nie vernünftig?“ „Darf ich Ihnen meinen Mann vorstellen?“ „Wer wird sich darüber noch aufregen?“

Comment: @user25172 Um upvoten zu können brauchst du 15 Reputationspunkte. Hast du die, ginge das auch als Gast.

Comment: @user25172 Und zu den fehlenden Punkten habe ich Dir gerade verholfen ;-)

Comment: Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass nach "Hast du das jetzt endlich kapiert?" in jedem Fall ein Fragezeichen gehört - egal, wie es gemeint ist.